# Which delegate to override for tuning the auto scrolling?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am getting really frustrated with this issue, I hope somebody could help me.

As you can see from the first screen the origin cursor position is in Password

[image]

Once you move your cursor to Email, the screen just moved a little bit up as shown in screenshot 2

[image]

I have tried to override the "textFieldDidBeginEditing"
and even add observer to the "keyboardWillShow notification" to get some control on the showing of key board.
But both doesn't work. It still moves just a little bit down, what I want is more. What I notice is that it only doesn't work when half line is covered/hidden if the whole textField is visible the "textFieldDidBeginEditing" is getting called properly.

I guess there must be some delegate method either related to tableView/ScrollView or related to keyboard or UIResponder which I am not sure, but need help from experienced developer.

Thanks

Comment: This is in a grouped table view?

Comment: And you want what, that it goes more towards the center of the screen?

Comment: You need to elaborate how this view is laid out - is it a grouped tableview like Kevin asked? Or is this a scroll view that you're manually moving the offset when the text field starts editing?

Comment: You guys are right, it is a grouped tableView. So do you guys know which delegate method I could override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a grouped table view. They automatically scroll a text field to visible when it becomes first responder. But, as you have found out, that means if the text field is half on the screen it just scrolls it all the way on, at the top (or bottom). If you want it to always show at a particular point on the screen, you'll need to calculate and set the offset yourself.  If you do it straight from the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` callback, though, it'll be overridden by the table's default scroll, so we delay it slightly.

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    double delayInSeconds = 0.01;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        CGRect bounds = textField.bounds;
        CGPoint offset = [self.tableView convertPoint:bounds.origin fromView:textField];
        offset.x = 0;
        offset.y -= 150;
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    });
}
```

Note that iOS 7's table scrolling is a bit buggy, so this may cause a bit of jumping. You can reduce the jumpiness by increasing the delay until after the auto-scroll, 0.25s should be good.

Comment: Really appreciate this solution Kevin. But I'm more looking forward to a solution where I can override some default delegate method so that I can control the behaviour tableView-wide other wise I need to manually calculate the distance for every textField, which I think is not a very good solution.

Comment: There's no magic delegate method. This code already calculates the distance for every text field. The only thing you need to change is the `-= 150`, adjust it for where on the screen you want the fields.

Comment: You could subclass the table and override the `setOffset:animated:` method, but good luck figuring out when you should or shouldn't block/change it.

Comment: I guess your solution is the best practice I can have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

     //if you just want to set the contentOffset when editing emailField add following condition
    if (textField==emailField) {

        float yOffSet = someValue;     

        [mytableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, yOffSet)];

        [emailField becomeFirstResponder];

    }
```